# Is the Assoc comand the only way to change a file type ext to a different file ext (eg. changing the .txt extension to .htm for text files)?

Tags: windows, command-line

I know that you can change the file ext for a file type to a different extension with the assoc command (e.g. Assoc .htm=textfile will make all textfiles have the .htm extension). Can this be done any other way?

Comment: Are you asking for _any_ other way or just other ways through command prompt?

Answer (score 0):

You can, of course, make changes through the Registry or from the context menu in Explorer (e.g. to set *Open with..*), but Nirsoft provides the free [File Types Manager](http://www.nirsoft.net/utils/file_types_manager.html), which provides a convenient GUI for changing multiple attributes of a file type.

However, rather than change the file type for .htm to textfile, which might interfere with applications such as browsers, just set the application you want to automatically open .htm files.